# "Delete files based on Invoice number, date and verison number"

Tags: python, python-3.x, file

I want to delete multiple files from certain directory based on file name, date and version number using Python. PS File creation date cant be taken into account

Refereed post of Stackoverflow but file names and version numbers are changed. How to keep date and version number to find latest file.

```
source = r'C:\Users\XMLFiles'
file_names = os.listdir(source)

latest_files = {}
for file_name in file_names:
    name_parts = file_name.split("_")
    date_stamp = name_parts[2], name_parts[3].split(".")[0]

    if date_stamp not in latest_files or file_name > latest_files[date_stamp]:
        latest_files[date_stamp] = file_name
        print(latest_files)

keep_files = latest_files.values()

for file_name in file_names:
    if file_name in keep_files:
        continue

    os.remove(os.path.join(source, file_name)




##################

List of files to process

=============================
Invoice_456879_20180404_2510.xml

Invoice_123876_20171027_17.xml
Invoice_123876_20180404_2513.xml

Invoice_832765_20170309_2.xml
Invoice_832765_20170313_0.xml
Invoice_832765_20170323_5.xml
Invoice_832765_20170330_2.xml
Invoice_832765_20170613_3.xml
Invoice_832765_20171206_18.xml
Invoice_832765_20171206_30.xml
Invoice_832765_20171206_36.xml
Invoice_832765_20180404_3066.xml
Invoice_832765_20180405_9770.xml
Invoice_832765_20180405_9779.xml

Invoice_698325_20170308_0.xml
Invoice_698325_20170309_3.xml
Invoice_698325_20170323_4.xml
Invoice_698325_20170330_5.xml
Invoice_698325_20170613_4.xml
Invoice_698325_20171206_8.xml
Invoice_698325_20171206_24.xml
Invoice_698325_20171206_46.xml
Invoice_698325_20180404_3067.xml
Invoice_698325_20180405_9771.xml

===========================================================

Expected Output

Invoice_456879_20180404_2510.xml
Invoice_123876_20180404_2513.xml
Invoice_832765_20180405_9779.xml
Invoice_698325_20180405_9771.xml
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
latest_files = {}

for file_name in file_names:
    name_parts = file_name.split('_')

    invoice = name_parts[1]
    ymd = name_parts[2]
    version = int(name_parts[3].split('.')[0])

    if invoice not in latest_files:
        latest_files[invoice] = (ymd, version, file_name)
        continue

    latest_ymd, latest_version = latest_files[invoice][:2]

    if ymd > latest_ymd or (ymd == latest_ymd and version > latest_version):
        latest_files[invoice] = (ymd, version, file_name)

keep_files = [tup[2] for tup in latest_files.values()]

for file_name in file_names:
    if file_name in keep_files:
        continue

    os.remove(os.path.join(source, file_name))
```

Comment: Thanks. Data is relevant. I need to check filename first, then date and then version number for every invoice. Code should delete the files for older datestamp first and then look for latest verison if there multiple files for same year-month-date.. Hope this clarifies.

Comment: Ah, I didn't notice that version depends on YMD. Edited.

Comment: Works like charm. Thanks!